# Why do we need to include filtrations in the definition of probability spaces when talking about stochastic processes.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, filtrations

In the first line of these notes the author defines his stochastic process. Using a filtration. What is the importance of filtrations?

https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/stefan_grosskinsky/ma4h3/ma4h3-0809/notes_ips_book.pdf

Comment: We want the stochastic process to be measurable for every time $t$. "Measurable with respect to what?" The filtration.

Comment: I can't access that link.

Comment: Cant you say measurable with respect to F instead of ${F_{t}$ where F is the smallest sigma-algebra which makes the mapping measurable for any t>0

Comment: Only if $F_t=F$, which is rarely the case.

Comment: Which mapping? Details and carefully written propositions already answer the question. To have a quick idea, imagine instead of a filtration $F=(F_t)_{t\in T=\{0,1,2,3,\dots\}}$ and and adapted process to it $X$ the following situation. The filtration is a newspaper providing information and $X$ is a TV sender using only the information from the newspaper. So at day $t$, the program $X_t$ can only tell stuff in the past journals. (To have a random variable, consider only the stock prices from the journal.)